# Component request is being processed

Tags: vb6

I see this message in VB6 again and again from time to time since I can remember, and now after like 15 years, I would like to ask if somebody knows how to get rid of this message.

I don't know when it occurs, but when it does, I can not click this window away.
It keeps flickering and does not go away:

[image]

In English:

*"The action cannot be completed because the other application is unavailable. Click 'Switch to' to activate the other application and fix the problem. 'Switch to...', 'Repeat', 'Cancel'* "

I don't really know what the message means. I would guess it wants to tell me that it waits for a component to respond.

But no longer how long I wait, it does not finish.

Does anybody know a trick how to close this window?
Sometimes I can still try to close VB6, and it *will* go away and allow me to save the edited files, but often, I have to terminate VB6 using the task mananger, and then my changes are lost.

I would like to avoid this.

Thank you!

Edit: It seems that the problem occurs when I use the clipboard.
Each time right now when I use Ctrl + V to paste something, this happens.

Comment: I assume you mean when pasting into the running app (as opposed to say the IDE).  Does it happen on all controls?  Text box?  Multiline text box?  In an input box?  In a grid cell?  Also, if you are able to, try compiling and see if you get the same in a compiled version?  Unless you have some active hooks on the controls in question, or are sub-classing, it seems to indicate either permissions, install, or OS obstruction.  Are you running as Administrator?